# How to do a live presentation by sharing android screen?

Tags: android, presentation, screensharing

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=64JulxSOjzc#t=1411s) you can see during the launch of Samsung Galaxy Nexus the presenter displays a live android screen. I have been searching far and wide for any software that can do the same.

I have seen apps like droid@screen but there is a huge lag while streaming the phone screen. While coming to hdpi devices the lag becomes huge and becomes a showstopper.

Is there any way I could attain the same quality and speed ?

Comment: Buy an MHL to HDMI adapter. The Galaxy Nexus and quite a few other devices support it.

Comment: Hmm looks like it's wireless in the presentation though

Comment: it's not wireless. They have a few devices not connected to show for the camera/audience but for the demonstration there's always an `anon` using the device that is plugged via HDMI. If you think the lag is huge on a stable WiFi, try on a WiFi with hundreds of bloggers connected and live blogging, not gonna happen. Furthermore, they use one of the Developer Options 'Show Touches' to show the finger position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach your Galaxy Nexus to an HDMI projector (or, for compatible hardware, use Miracast, a.k.a., Samsung AllShare).

Or, root your Galaxy Nexus and find some software that can work directly with the framebuffer for this.

Droid@Screen is as fast as you can get using semi-supported techniques.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the cable, [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market.samsung&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS50ZWFtdmlld2VyLnF1aWNrc3VwcG9ydC5tYXJrZXQuc2Ftc3VuZyJd) is also an alternative, just tried it on Samsung Galaxy S3 and works like charm.

Comment: TeamViewer QuickSupport will help you control an android device using a computer. But here on the contrary I am trying to have my android screen projected to the large display.
Anyways thanks Ales